# Tabhost content getting appended on switching Tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am facing an issue while using TabHost and switching between the tabs. I have placed the Tabs at the bottom and have provided separate intents for each of the tabs as shown below :-

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,BottomTabs.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Home",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,BottomTabWebsite.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Website",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.website1))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MSIDates.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("social").setIndicator("Dates",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.memory_lane))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BottomTabExit.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("contact").setIndicator("Exit",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.exit))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

No on switching from 1 tab to another, the content of the next tab is being shown just below the content of the earlier tab. In short the content of first tab is not getting cleared. Though i have set the content view of the activity related to the next tab to other layout. Is there anything that i need to take care to make sure that the content of earlier tab gets overridden with the tab's content which has been selected?